# Using ws and wss simultaneously

Tags: node.js, http, https, websocket

I am trying to get both `ws` and `wss` working, on one WebSocket server.

This is what I currently have, only `wss`

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var https = require('https');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('cert/key.key');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('cert/cert.crt');

var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    ca: ca,
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, this.app);

var options = {
    server: httpsServer, 
    perMessageDeflate: false,
    maxPayload: 4096
};

var wss = new WebSocket.Server(options);
```

I know using Socket.io it is really easy, you can just do `io.attach(httpServer)` and `io.attach(httpsServer)`.

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(this.app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    key: privateKey,
    cert: certificate
}, this.app);

httpServer.listen(3002, function(){
    console.log('httpServer listening on port 3002');
});

httpsServer.listen(3003, function(){
    console.log('httpsServer listening on port 3003');
});

this.io = new ioServer();
this.io.attach(httpServer);
this.io.attach(httpsServer);
```

Is this even possible, using this [WebSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) library?

Comment: What do you mean simultaneously? Running both of them?

Comment: Yes, running both of them, acting as one server.

Comment: you just need to provide 2 different servers on different ports. Firstr one http, second one https.

Comment: Yes, I have just realized that. I could not think straight for a moment.